# Can SMD 22uH (shielded) inductor cause health hazards?

Tags: inductor

I'm planning to add MT3608 boost converter to gloves, for experimental purposes. I'm planning to use SMD 22uH (shielded) for it, because I have seen such a schematic in many places, and its allowed by the specs. Planning to use 5 V or 6 V.

Can the SMD 22uH (shielded) inductor cause health hazards, when its constantly near a hand?

Comment: Why do you think it would be a health hazard?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not related to electrical engineering.

Comment: You should be more worried about possible burns if something goes wrong with your circuit than any electrical/magnetic effects. (Assuming you don't bring mains power to your glove...)

Comment: @SteveSh Because, I have no reason to be certain, so I doubt.

Comment: @verbessern - It's hard, maybe impossible, to prove a negative.

Comment: If you eat it, maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short anwer: No

Longer answer: Only if you eat it

There are no known effects of low power low frequency (non ionizing) radiation on the human body. So it doesen't even matter if your coil is shielded or not.

Current data in the scientific community is at best inconclusive or even contradictionary. Studies that see effects are not reproducible suggesting that instead of mesuring an EM effect the result was some random fluctuation in the data obtained.